# pidof giving two numbers which is process id or pid. please tell

Tags: c, linux, unix, process

when I run the command

```
pidof lh
```

for lh program, I get two values. what are they. I was looking of pid of `lh` running program so I can increase the number of open files limit https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/422732/211761

Why i am getting two values, if one is pid then what is the other

OUTPUT

```
  37354 7968
```

which one above is pid and what is the other number. please tell

Comment: Have you read the man page?  Can it be that you have two processes running the `lh` program in your system?  Voted to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both. You have two lh processes running.

Comment: can a C thread considered as process or pid. The program `lh` creates thread./ and show up in pidof command separately

Comment: ok I got the answer but can u please tell do I need to set open file limit for which pid or should I set ulimit for both pid for allowing to increase files open limit https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=can+a+program+thread+has+its+own+pid

Comment: I set the choice for both processes. I create thread and I close it after fulfilling the request but I dont know why I am still getting multiple processes. Is there a way I can get specific tcp port number number of connections for open files and file names like either socket or file

Comment: @user786 probably because you have two lh processes running...